# How to add a border or set transparent a QLayout in PySide2?

Tags: python, qt, pyside2

I'm doing an addon for Blender and I'm using PySide2. I was able to remove the Window Title and appear only the content of the window. I inserted an animated gif inside a QFrame and changed the border of it. The problem is that the container still have its sharp borders appearing.

Is there any way to change a QLayout style?
I wish to add corners to the QLayout or set it to transparent instead of white.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super(Ui_Form, self).__init__(parent)
    #size of the container of gif
    self.size = QtCore.QSize(160, 100)
    self.pixel = QtGui.QMovie(
        '/home/mateus/Documents/Blender Projects/blender_pyside2_example-master/gui/img.gif')
    self.pixel.setScaledSize(self.size)
    #size of the window
    self.setFixedSize(160, 100)
    #style of with rounded corners
    self.setStyleSheet("""
    QFrame{
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: rgba(55, 55, 55, 255);
        border-width: 3px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        background-color: rgba(55, 55, 55, 255);
    }
    """)

    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel()
    self.label.setMovie(self.pixel)
    self.pixel.start()
    self.label.show()

    layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    layout.setMargin(0)
    #attach gif to layout
    layout.addWidget(self.label)

    self.unsetCursor()

    self.setLayout(layout)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make the window transparent:

```
self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)
self.setStyleSheet("""
QWidget{
    background: transparent;
}
QFrame{
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: rgba(55, 55, 55, 255);
    border-width: 3px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: rgba(55, 55, 55, 255);
}
""")
```

<sup>Note: The layout is not a graphic element so it cannot be made transparent, what has to be made transparent is the container.</sup>

Comment: Thank you @eylllanesc. This really worked! Nice and clean.